# Who was indicated as the Creator, the Christ and holy servant in the prayer of Jesus' disciples in Acts 4:24-30?

Tags: acts

> Acts 4:24-30 And when they heard it, they lifted their voices together to God and said, “Sovereign Lord, who made the heaven and the earth and the sea and everything in them, who through the mouth of our father David, your servant, said by the Holy Spirit,

> “‘Why did the Gentiles rage,
> and the peoples plot in vain?
> 26The kings of the earth set themselves,
> and the rulers were gathered together,
> against the Lord and against his Anointed’—

> 27for truly in this city there were gathered together against your holy servant Jesus, whom you anointed, both Herod and Pontius Pilate, along with the Gentiles and the peoples of Israel, 28to do whatever your hand and your plan had predestined to take place.  ESV

Who was indicated as the Creator, Messiah and God's holy servant in the prayer of Jesus' disciples in these verses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems clear that God (Father, Sovereign Lord) who anointed Jesus *and* David, is the creator of all that existed - as the Jews would have always understood and believed, clearly differentiating God as Creator from his servants.

The quoted passage in Acts is from Psalm 2 foretelling of the anointing process of the one to come.

> He said to me, ‘You are My Son, Today I have fathered You. ‘Ask it of Me, and I will certainly give the nations as your inheritance, And the ends of the earth as your possession. 9‘You shall break them with a rod of iron, you shall shatter them like earthenware.’ Ps 2:7-9

> The one who overcomes, and the one who keeps my deeds until the end, I will give him authority over the nations; 27AND HE SHALL RULE THEM WITH A ROD OF IRON, AS THE VESSELS OF THE POTTER ARE SHATTERED, as I also have received authority from my Father Rev 2:26-7 NASB

Jesus is God's servant Acts 3:26, Matt 12:18, Acts 4:30 as was David before him - a forerunner of Jesus as king and God's special anointed one etc. who would eventually become God's heir. Heb 1

Comment: Eph 4:6, Matt 23:9, Is 64:8, Mal 2:10 (One Father who created us) 2 Cor 1:3b, Is 63:16, 1 John 3:1...…………………………..

Comment: Above was response to a query re God named as Father apart from as Jesus' Father. - which has been deleted I assume.